# How Bootstrap dialog open a vue component page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

We have a Bootstrap project, but we also need to open a cron editor component on web page which is developed by vue framework, is there a way to make it happen between these two different web frameworks?

[Cron Expression Editor in Vue](https://karoletrych.github.io/vue-cron-editor/)

The Bootstrap project is already exist for many days, and we can't upgrade it by Vue. It seems that we can't open the Vue component page(CronEditor) directly through a html page based pure javascript.

Could someone make any suggestions here? Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS framework, Vue is a JS framework. Both can totally work together. Meanwhile, usually you use `bootstrap-vue` to work in a state-based approach and being able to pass data/toggle things around with Vue.

Comment: Vue is incrementally adoptable. This means you can use it to render the smallest part of any web page (e.g: a button) and it doesn't care much what framework powers that page (unless it's a different version of Vue, but that's a whole different set of problems). It appears the cron editor uses vue@2. Most vue developers would be able to implement it into any vanilla project.